# how do I horizontally center a div that only has a max-width and has fixed positioning?

Tags: css, css-position

I have been trying to figure out a solution for this and have been searching forums but thy only talk about percentages.

I have a div that contains text only. I need it to have a max-width of 700px, be positioned fixed and be centered horizontally on the screen.

In a perfect world, this is what I want to work but of course it won't:

```
<div style="max-width: 700px; text-align: center; position: fixed; bottom: 40px; margin: auto;">sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `left:0;right:0;`

```
<div style="max-width: 700px; text-align: center; position: fixed; bottom: 40px; margin: auto;left:0;right:0;">sample text</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/vp8EF/4/)

Comment: I just noticed that this works in firefox but it is not working in the current version of internet explorer. Is there anything that can be done to fix that?

Comment: I figured it out. I also had to add width: 100% for it to work in Internet explorer.